# Кракозябры в комментарии к коммиту

Tags: intellij-idea

Отдельные комментарии к коммитам в IntelliJ IDEA превращаются в кракозябры. Причём на моём компьютере все комментарии отображаются нормально, а на других отдельные комментарии (не все, только некоторые - те, которые были отредактированы после создания!..) превращаются в кракозябры. Как это можно исправить? От каких настроек IDEA это зависит?

Comment: где именно они отображаются неправильно?

Comment: @Grundy, во вкладке "Version Control > Repository"

Comment: Комментарии с не латинскими символами? На какой системе это все запускается?

Comment: @Grundy, да, с кириллицей; windows

Comment: Возможно поможет выставление настроек Windows для неюникодных программ.

Comment: Попробуй в настройках компьютера где плохо показываются посмотреть `Language for non-Unicode programs`: control panel -> region -> administrative

Comment: Есть какие-то изменения?

Comment: @Grundy, на моём компьютере (с которого был сделан коммит) Current language for non-Unicode programs - Russian (Russia), а на компьютере, где комментарий был виден как кракозябры - English (United States). Как лучше привести всё к общему знаменателю - выставить везде язык как Russian или же как English?

Comment: Скорее всего: _выставить везде как язык как Russian_, хотя можно попробовать и так и так. А возможно сам язык значения не имеет, главное чтобы было одинаково у всех

Comment: Благодарю! Не знаю, как протестировать, что это точно было причиной, потому что не все комментарии превращались в кракозябры, а только некоторые, но, думаю, что это и есть ответ на мой вопрос, очень логично)

Comment: Тогда напиши ответ, как проверишь

Comment: @Grundy, я сначала изменила этот язык, но потом всё-таки откатила изменения - потому как во всех остальных программах, типа Notepad++, все файлы с кириллицей стали отображаться кракозябрами. Слишком большие накладные расходы...)